# Display data from json file in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, sorting

I Have the following Json file and i want to output data as categories(pizza, pasta) and then sub-categories(pizza margherita, pizza prosciutto) and same for pasta and for each to have choices, exactly as the structure in the file.

This is json file which i wanted to output it. I use ngfor to loop through the array but how to display from first option, both categories?

```
    [
    {
    "name" : "Pizza", 
    "category": [
        {
            "name": "Pizza Marquerita",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Crust",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Crispy"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Fluffy"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Extra Toppings",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Olives"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Mushrooms"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Pizza Prosciutto",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Crust",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Crispy"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Fluffy"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Extra Toppings",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Olives"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Mushrooms"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "choices": [
        {
            "name": "Crust",
            "addons" : [
                {
                    "name": "Crispy"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Fluffy"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Extra Toppings",
            "addons" : [
                {
                    "name": "Olives"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mushrooms"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]},
    {
    "name" : "Pasta", 
    "category": [
        {
            "name": "Spaghetti Bolognese",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Pasta Type",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Spaghetti"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Tagliatelle"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Extra Toppings",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "extra sea food"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "truffle"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Spaghetti Frutti di Mare",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Pasta Type",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Spaghetti"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Tagliatelle"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Extra Toppings",
                    "addons" : [
                        {
                            "name": "extra sea food"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "truffle"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "choices": [
        {
            "name": "Pasta Type",
            "addons" : [
                {
                    "name": "Spaghetti"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tagliatelle"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Extra Toppings",
            "addons" : [
                {
                    "name": "extra sea food"
                },
                {
                    "name": "truffle"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}

]
```

In .ts file i import the file
import data from '../../assets/data.json'; and then declare it as menus: any = data;

in html i want to output data as a card just something simple. If i use it like that. it displays pizza margherita and spaghetti bolognese under pizza

```
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Restaurant Name</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-header">Pizza</div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let menu of menus">{{menu.category[0].name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-header">Pasta</div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly post your code/effort then only we can help you debug.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth just added code from .ts and html file. I just want something basic for it, just to output data in the format of json. Thanks

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON data before performing any operations?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth no. That is all i did so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this code:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Restaurant Name</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-header">Pizza</div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let menu of menus[0].category">{{menu.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-header">Pasta</div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let menu1 of menus[1].category">{{menu1.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You have to use correct ngfor elements.

`{{menu.category[0].name}}` will only give 1st category name of Pizza.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it but i get this error when i check console ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: fixed it. the error was at menus.category[0]. I changed it to menus[0].category and it works perfect. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below code. I think it will be a remove redundant code.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Restaurant Name</h5>
    </div>
    <span *ngFor="let data of menus">
        <div class="card-header">{{data.name}}</div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let menu of data.category">{{menu.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

and your data is here

```
menus: any = [
    {
    name : "Pizza", 
    category: [
        {
            name: "Pizza Marquerita",
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "Crust",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "Crispy"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Fluffy"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Extra Toppings",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "Olives"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Mushrooms"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Pizza Prosciutto",
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "Crust",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "Crispy"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Fluffy"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Extra Toppings",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "Olives"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Mushrooms"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    choices: [
        {
            name: "Crust",
            addons : [
                {
                    name: "Crispy"
                },
                {
                    name: "Fluffy"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Extra Toppings",
            addons : [
                {
                    name: "Olives"
                },
                {
                    name: "Mushrooms"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]},
    {
    name : "Pasta", 
    category: [
        {
            name: "Spaghetti Bolognese",
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "Pasta Type",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            "name": "Spaghetti"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Tagliatelle"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Extra Toppings",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "extra sea food"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "truffle"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Spaghetti Frutti di Mare",
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "Pasta Type",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "Spaghetti"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Tagliatelle"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Extra Toppings",
                    addons : [
                        {
                            name: "extra sea food"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "truffle"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    choices: [
        {
            name: "Pasta Type",
            addons : [
                {
                    name: "Spaghetti"
                },
                {
                    name: "Tagliatelle"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Extra Toppings",
            addons : [
                {
                    name: "extra sea food"
                },
                {
                    name: "truffle"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}
]
```